# Eclipse Mars toolbar entries have several gaps

Tags: java, eclipse

I've updated eclipse from luna to mars and the toolbar entries have large gaps in them. Right clicking the toolbar and pressing "Restore Hidden Toolbar Entries" does nothing.

I am using Windows 10 64bit and Java8u60. What it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLKYK.png

Is there a reason for the spacing or a way to put it back to normal?

Answer (score 3):

What helped me after I tried everything, including a recreation of the workspace, was to **open a new Eclipse window (Window > New Window)**. There were no gaps in the toolbar and the toolbar was editable again. So I closed the bugged window **and restarted Eclipse**. I have not seen this problem since then.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Opening a new window (Window > New Window) worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you hover at the right side of a space, the mouse should change to a 4-way arrow. You can then click and drag to the left to remove the spacing.

Comment: I just tried this and the 4-way arrow does not appear.

Comment: I have no idea how it fixed itself but for some reason it went away and now  the float-able separators are back in place of the spaces. Something was wrong with the separators.

Answer (score 2):

This can be quickly and easily solved by doing the following:

1. Navigate to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Appearance**
2. Ensure that the following two settings are configured like so:

   - **Theme**: Classic
   - **Color and Font Theme**: Default (current)

This, together with a restart, properly the sets the toolbar icons and removes the gaps. It also prevents another annoying glitch, in which the perspective icons to the far right would be randomly and inexplicably bumped down to a second menu line, taking up screen space, when opening a file in the editor.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.